# Can not delete L.circle or L.polygon added programmatically but L.markers are fine

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to persist drawn items across page refreshes but running into issues with circles, polygons and markers.  Markers work fine but circles and polygons are not removable:

```
// basic map setup taken from tutorial
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems
  },
  draw: {
    polyline: false
  }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);

// this works fine and the markers are able to be deleted by the delete control
var pointMarker = new L.marker(new L.LatLng(pointLat, pointLon));
pointMarker.addTo(drawnItems);

// this will draw the circle/polygon
// it is not selectable for deletion using the remove toolbar
// other circles/polygons created using the draw toolbar are removable
var circle = new L.circle(new L.LatLng(circleLat, circleLon), circleRadius);
circle.addTo(drawnItems);
```

On other note: the edit toolbar button does allow the circle/polygons to be edited so there is clearly some differences between the remove and edit functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your created items directly to the drawnItems in the draw:created event. Here's what I'm doing and I'm able to add and remove all types.

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
            var type = e.layerType,
                layer = e.layer;

            drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
        });
```